# Reference Error: can't find variable in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error when i run the app on android

[image]

My AppNavigation code as follow

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Home from '../pages/Home'
import DetailsAdd from '../pages/DetailsAdd'
import ImagesAdd from '../pages/ImagesAdd'

const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    DetailsAdd: { screen: DetailsAdd },
    ImagesAdd: { screen: ImagesAdd },
    Home: { screen: Home },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
)

export default AppNavigation

  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppNavigator/>;
  }
}
```

`ImagesAdd` Class path is correct, How can I fix this issue?

Comment: try to close node server and rerun app

Answer (score 2):

Have you got any app container? if you not, you should check [this link](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Hello%20World&dependencies=react-navigation%2Creact-navigation-stack%2Creact-navigation-tabs%2Creact-navigation-drawer&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F4.x%2Fhello-react-navigation.js).

**important note from React Navigation Docs**

***createStackNavigator*** is a function that returns a React component. It takes a route configuration object and, optionally, an options object (we omit this below, for now). **createAppContainer** is a function that returns a React component to take as a parameter the React component created by the createStackNavigator, and can be directly exported from App.js to be used as our App's root component.